# подсчет строк с одинаковым временем

Tags: sql, postgresql

на машине есть датчик движения, каждую секунду он считывает данные о местоположении и вносит их в таблицу, нужно посчитать сколько раз машина была в одной конкретной точке за день, объединив множество значений за минуту в одно. Подскажите пожалуйста[image: вид тыблицы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть вам подойдёт такой вариант:

```
Create temp table tmpTable as
    select addr,zone_id,DATE_PART('hour',time)*100+DATE_PART('minute',time) as IntTime from sometable where time between '2022.04.04' and '2022.04.05';
select addr,zone_id,IntTime,count(*) as cnt from tmpTable group by addr,zone_id,IntTime order by IntTime;
```

Здесь мы делаем следующее: выбираем записи, где время интерпретируем как значение часов умножить на 100, плюс количество минут, а потом их группируем с подсчётом.

Comment: Cпасибо!! А вот вы сгруппировали значения за одну минуту, а можно ли как нибудь их сгруппировать за 10 минут? или такое невозможно?

Comment: Всё можно. Ту часть в запросе, которая берёт минуты нужно разделить на 10.
DATE_PART('minute',time) -> DATE_PART('minute',time)/10
Так как это будет целочисленное деление, то остаток отбросится и получится группировка по 10 минут.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно, если я верно понял задачу https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/87PAeff1YTmVp6M4C9wxdf/0

Если надо разбиение не по минутам, а по дням - измените формат в to_char с DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI на DD Mon YYYY

Ну и дальше можно накидывать свои условия для выборки по желанию